# Recovering Windows Vista Partition after Ubuntu Natty N. install

Tags: ubuntu, windows-vista, grub2

I recently installed Ubuntu on my DELL's D Drive (Secondary Partition) and I lost the windows vista boot which was on my C Drive. Now when I boot my system directly loads Ubuntu, which seemed to me that GRUB was not installed. So I installed GRUB2

```
sudo apt-get install grub-pc
```

I checked the version to get:

```
$ grub-install -v
grub-install (GRUB) 1.99~rc1-13ubuntu3
```

Now how do I configure grub to list both Ubuntu (sda5) and windows vista (sda3)? Or that is not possible :(

The Catch:

My CD drive is broken so I cant use any Live CD

PS: I have a mem-stick with Ubuntu installed

Answer (score 0):

Try running this to see if Grub will add Windows to its menu:

```
update-grub
```

---

Make a new file, `/etc/grub.d/11_windows`, with this content:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
echo "found Windows Vista" >&2
cat << EOF
menuentry "Windows Vista" {
    set root=(hd0,3)
    chainloader +1
}
EOF
```

Then run

```
update-grub
```

again.

Comment: I dont think so, this is the out put which i get:
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-10-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-10-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-8-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-8-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done

Comment: I've edited my answer with a new solution; please give that a go.

Comment: nope , the output is the same as above ... no sign of window

Comment: Make sure that the `11_windows` file you have made has the executable bit enabled, and try again.

Comment: great...
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-10-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-10-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-8-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-8-generic
found Windows Vista
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done
............. it worked...now what should i do?

Comment: Reboot, and see if you can find Windows Vista in Grub's menu. If the menu does not appear automatically, hold 'shift' while booting.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Windows installation CD, follow these steps:

1. Insert the Windows installation disk (may be a USB drive).
2. Restart the computer (making sure that the BIOS is configured to boot from that).
3. Once started and loaded, choose the "Repair your computer" option.
4. From the next set of options, select "Startup Repair". Once complete the computer will restart and the problem should be solved.

Comment: In the future, please don't cross-post on multiple Stack Exchange sites. Thanks.